# Binding between UI and JavaScript: Different scopes?

Tags: javascript

I have a web app. In this app, I have a page of dynamically built editable items. I have the editing portion working just fine. My problem is, I'm unable to bind changes from the input element back to my data structure. I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4amsbq6t/1/). My relevant code looks like this:

```
var options = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $.material.init();
  });

  // Initialize the options
  options.push({ id:1, html:'' });
  options.push({ id:2, html:'' });
  options.push({ id:3, html:'' });

  var optionEditors = $('.option-editor');
  for (var i=0; i<optionEditors.length; i++) {
    $(optionEditors[i]).summernote({
      airMode: true,
      popover: {
        air: [
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']]
        ]
      },
      callbacks: {
        onInit: function() {
          var editor = $('.note-editor');
          editor.addClass('form-control');
          editor.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', onUpdate);
          $(this).summernote('code', ' ');

          var editable = editor.find('.note-editable');
          editable.attr('data-id', $(this).attr('data-id'));
          editable.attr('data-index', $(this).attr('data-index'));          
        }
      }      
    });    
  }
});

function onUpdate(option) {
    try {
      var id = choice.target.getAttribute('data-id');
      var index = choice.target.getAttribute('data-index');
      alert(id + ' : ' + index) 
      options[index].html = choice.target.innerHTML;
    } catch (ex) {
  }
}
```

It's almost like the `options` variable is in a different scope. It's so weird. Basically, when the text in any of the input fields gets updated the `options` content should get updated as well. Such that when I click the `Print` button, I can see the contents of the `options` variable in the console window. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: can't see how this would work. NOWHERE in your for() loop do you access or change `options`. There's literally no connection from `options` to the rest of the code.

Comment: @MarcB The idea is the `onUpdate` is responsible for updating the `options` collection. The `onUpdate` function is fired when a change is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var id = choice.target.getAttribute('data-id');` on this line `choice` is undefined. Maybe that's the problem?